# How to recreate an MP4 file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to replace an MP4 file played back in a relatively restricted environment and so I am trying to create a video file as close to the current one as possible to make sure it'll work. `ffprobe` has this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2016-12-07T20:39:51.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013051800
  Duration: 00:00:11.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4789 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 4648 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
```

I do not know how to specify `mp42` and `mp42isomavc1`. The rest I have some ideas about: `-vf` supports `setsar` and `setdar`, `-pix_fmt yuv420p`,  `-framerate 24`.

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: I copied what ffprobe says about the input , not sure what else you need...?

Comment: So, you are transcoding this file into a new one with the same properties? Current versions of ffmpeg will automatically create, by default, MP4s with major brand `mp42`. `framerate` is applicable only for raw, captured or image seq. inputs. Which is why I asked you for the input type.

Comment: No, I am trying to create a new MP4 file to replace `input.mp4`. I have wide control over the source but it should match the original `input.mp4` closely because I do not know what the decoder will accept there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you start with a video input and that resolution doesn't matter, use

```
ffmpeg -i source -vf setsar=1,format=yuv420p -r 24 \
       -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -video_track_timescale 90k \
       -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -color_range 1 \
       -brand mp42 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

FFmpeg does not allow one to manually set the `minor_version`. When encoding, the encoder will select a codec time base `tbc` and it's not recommended to manually set it. The color properties are set to match your given input but if your source has different properties and you don't convert them using filters, then these attributes will be false. Of course, your decoder may ignore these container level flags and check only the bitstream.

If your input framerate isn't 24, then ffmpeg will drop/duplicate frames to meet the output rate. Unless your input has a framerate not supported by the player, better to skip the `-r` option.